# Return value of a REG QUERY cmd

Tags: batch-file, registry, uac

first of all sorry for my bad english.
i have to check, if uac is running or not.

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA
```

This command returns 0x0 when UAC isn't running, otherwise 0x1.
But it returns with other useless stuff that i'm still not needing.

is there any possibilitie to only filter the 0x0/0x1 into a variable an save it to a txt file?

Comment: If you want to know if user has admin powers then create a file in c:\windows, if it succeeds they do, if it fails, they don't. `echo. >c:\windows\uac.txt && echo Is an Admin || echo Is NOT an Admin`.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with both NSIS and batch-file? Do you need the answer in a batch file or in NSIS?

Comment: I didn't know what i should write in the tags, thats all. I found an other way to check, in NSIS itself. Thanks for helping guys :).

Comment: Your question is actually, "how do I know if I am running elevated?", not "how do I tell if UAC is enabled?" Thus the answer you marked actually isn't the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (
    'REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA'
) do set "UAC=%%a"

> "someFile.txt" echo %UAC%
```

The `for /f` will execute the command, read its output and split the lines using the spaces and tabs as delimiters. We are asking for the third token. As the usual output of `reg` command is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

there is only one line with at least three tokens, so only this line will be processed. As we are requesting the third token, the `0x1` is stored in the `for` replaceable parameter, that is assigned to the `%UAC%` variable.

Then, the value of the variable is echoed to the indicated file

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i were looking for

Comment: Actually, that's not what you were looking for. As Anders pointed out, that registry value does not reflect the current UAC state. That isn't your question, anyway. What you really want to know is whether you're running elevated, not whether UAC is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

EnableLUA is not the true UAC state, it can be out of date. If you change the UAC settings without rebooting then EnableLUA will give you the wrong value.

There is no documented way to get the current UAC state as far as I know...